# Schedulertask to index storage fails

Tags: typo3, scheduled-tasks, rights, typo3-8.7.x, fal

I have some additional folders added to my installation at web-root. these folders are synced from extern and should be indexed regulary for TYPO3 (later on they are indexed by solrfal, which stalls with the same error).

While the scheduler jobs run some (for some storages) terminate with the error `Execution failed: 1430657869, You are not allowed to read folders`. But all folders have (meanwhile) the access right set to 777 recursively. There also are no symlinks.

In file list module all folders and files are fully accessible (read and write).

I even set the *CLI* user to admin =:O

**Why does the error occur?**

**Where does the error occur?** (what folder?)

Comment: does it happen too if you rename .htaccess?

Comment: btw: 644 should be enough ...

Comment: We have no active .htaccess in folders. there is a apache config for the usual TYPO3 htaccess rules. I don't understand why .htaccess hould be relevant. the access is in the local file system by FAL.

Comment: we have slight missmatch about my primary group and the apache user. And to avoid any problems with access rights I set 777. But the problems seems to be another.

Comment: I'd try to deactivate the main .htaccess for TYPO3. Reason is that in htaccess for some folders are granted some rights - and others therefore excluded.

Comment: seems you configured the folders as file-storage as you wrote it's in FAL. Is that right?

Comment: yes. each folder a file storage, all storages and subfolders can be accessed in file list module without errors or warnings

Comment: as these folders are outside of TYPO3 folder structure they should not be  affected by any TYPO3 .htaccess settings.

Comment: Then you've to wait for someone else because I've no other idea ;-)

Comment: thanks to you anyway

Comment: There is one rule `

 # Stop rewrite processing, if we are in the typo3/ directory or any other known directory
 # NOTE: Add your additional local storages here
 RewriteRule ^(?:typo3/|fileadmin/|typo3conf/|typo3temp/|uploads/|favicon\.ico) - [L]` there you could add your folders